# Azure Bot Service Direct Line API v3.0 constantly throwing 403 error on starting conversation

Tags: azure, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have been trying to utilize Azure Direct Line API v3.0 for a bot. However it seems I am no longer enable to start a conversation as I am getting 403 message on APi call. Here is my call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate",
        method: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            /* Authorization header */
            xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("Bearer:GI3UQr2GYoA.cwA.wHo.h1AyNQKXSESWZGFrf-yf_Cm3XwDRy38Yn-xzgUton-E"));
        },
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }
    });
```

Mind you, this used to work couple of days back. I have several activity records for activities created through this API.

But now I am getting this error message constantly on even getting token:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Missing token or secret"
  }
}
```

I am using free subscription plan and I have 7 days remaining. Also I have checked the subscription status, its active. I have over $140 in credit too.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong and why would this stop working all of a sudden?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the doc provided by MS about the authentication: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

It says:

```
Authorization: Bearer SECRET_OR_TOKEN
```

So change this line:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("Bearer:GI3UQr2GYoA.cwA.wHo.h1AyNQKXSESWZGFrf-yf_Cm3XwDRy38Yn-xzgUton-E"));
```

To:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Bearer GI3UQr2GYoA.cwA.wHo.h1AyNQKXSESWZGFrf-yf_Cm3XwDRy38Yn-xzgUton-E");
```

And it works fine!

[image]